# Square Connect SDK opens a blank page

Tags: square-connect

I am attempting to implement Square Connect iOS SDK, and after implementing and clicking the pay button it opens up the Square Payment app and redirects to a blank page .. have you guys had the same issues ?

My App delegate has the proper section:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        guard let sourceApplication = options[.sourceApplication] as? String,
            sourceApplication.hasPrefix("com.squareup.square") else {
                return false
        }

        do {
            let response = try SCCAPIResponse(responseURL: url)

            if let error = response.error {
                // Handle a failed request.
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                // Handle a successful request.
            }

        } catch let error as NSError {
            // Handle unexpected errors.
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

        return true
    }
```

I have created a proper URL scheme inside the Square portal. Also my view controller has the correct code:

```
func charge()
{
    // connect v1

    if let callbackURL = URL(string: "myscheme://")
    {
        do
        {
            SCCAPIRequest.setClientID("xxxxxxxxxxx")
            let amount = try SCCMoney(amountCents: 100, currencyCode: "USD")

            let request = try SCCAPIRequest(
                callbackURL: callbackURL,
                amount: amount,
                userInfoString: nil,
                locationID: nil,
                notes: "Purchase for cleaning",
                customerID: nil, supportedTenderTypes: .all,
                clearsDefaultFees: true,
                returnAutomaticallyAfterPayment: true)

            try SCCAPIConnection.perform(request)
        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

https://snag.gy/R4A30L.jpg

Andrei

Comment: My App delegate has the proper section:

`code`

Comment: By blank page, are you meaning it's opening your app with a blank view, or it's still in the POS app and it's just blank? Are you receiving any error? Are you logged into the POS application?

Comment: I figured it out, it was actually deploying two applications. So if anybody runs into the same issue check to make sure you don't have two apps installed with same bundle id but different apps. After removing both applications and re-installing iOS app it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you delete all apps from the phone with having duplicate bundle ids. This way you will make sure you go back to the original app which triggered the payment.